# How to zip multiple files into zip with Copy-ToZip from PowerShellPack?

Tags: powershell, zip

I installed the [PowerShellPack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPack) to zip multiple files into zip.
It works with small files like .txt, but not with large files.
Only one file is in the zip and I get the error `File not found or no read permission`.

```
Import-Module PowerShellPack
Copy-ToZip -File "D:\Temp\Test.adi" -zipfile "D:\Temp\Files.zip"
Copy-ToZip -File "D:\Temp\Test2.adt" -zipfile "D:\Temp\Files.zip"
```

I tried to use the Wait-Job command, but this also only works with small files.
With large files a zip-file is created, but it is empty.

```
Import-Module PowerShellPack
$job = Start-Job {Copy-ToZip -File "D:\Temp\Test.adi" -zipfile "D:\Temp\Files.zip"}
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job
$job = Start-Job {Copy-ToZip -File "D:\Temp\Test2.adt" -zipfile "D:\Temp\Files.zip"}
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job
```

Comment: Probably related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699767/copy-folder-contents-to-a-created-zip-file-file-not-found-or-no-read-permissi

Comment: Sorry, even I got the issue when I put up all these lines in one PS script file and ran it. I ran it earlier one by one. It seems like a bug in PowerShellPack

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the Write-Zip cmdlet included in the [PowerShell Community Extensions](https://pscx.codeplex.com/) instead. It doesn't have the file access problems that Copy-ToZip has.

Example usage:

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Temp\*.ad* | Write-Zip -OutputPath D:\Temp\Files.zip
```

If `-OutputPath` is not specified, a zip file will be created for each input file rather than a single zip file.

It also has a `-Level` switch to specify compression level.

Comment: real nice package =)