# Powershell v2 zip function isn't zipping everything

Tags: powershell, zip, powershell-2.0

I can't quite remember where I found the answer that led me to use this Powershell snippet, but I've been using this script to zip a folder and the files contained within it:

```
param (
[string]$ZipFrom,
[string]$ZipTo
)
function Add-Zip
{
    param([string]$zipfilename)

    if(-not (test-path($zipfilename)))
    {
        set-content $zipfilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
    (dir $zipfilename).IsReadOnly = $false  
    }

    $shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application
    $zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfilename)

    foreach($file in $input) 
    { 
        $zipPackage.CopyHere($file.FullName)
        Start-sleep -milliseconds 500
    }
}

If(Test-path $ZipTo) {Remove-item $ZipTo}

dir $ZipFrom -Recurse | Add-Zip $ZipTo
```

Not sure what I'm missing, but it seems like it's zipping HALF of the files within the folder. I just tried this on a folder with 62 files in it, and I ended up with a zip archive with 31 files in it.

Comment: Are the other files perhaps hidden? `dir $ZipFrom -Recurse -force | Add-Zip $ZipTo`. Does `dir $ZipFrom -Recurse`  show _all the files_ that should be zipped?

Comment: None of the missing files are marked as hidden, good thought though.

Comment: @Matt running just the `dir $ZipFrom -Recurse` does show all files.

Comment: Have you run this in interactive mode? I am guessing not because I think you are getting _File not found or no read permission_ errors.

Comment: Is the number of files that successfully get zipped the same _every time_? Need to test more but I find it changes based on the sleep time I set.

Comment: Do you get a tmp file with the same basename as the zip created as well?

Comment: I am guessing that `CopyHere()` is not waiting for the file to finish being zipped and it is having issues doing multiple operations at once. perhaps a larger timeout, for testing purposes, would compensate for this Surely this is documented somewhere.

Comment: Not useful but https://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000774 suggests that size is an issue.

Comment: This also might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699767/copy-folder-contents-to-a-created-zip-file-file-not-found-or-no-read-permissi

Comment: Looks like several of the largest files to be zipped ARE making it through the process, so while the KB article above is worth noting, I don't think it's the issue here.

Comment: why zip a file like this?

Comment: @ArcSet access to 7Zip was removed in the environment I'm working in.

Comment: Did you have a look at my other comments?

Comment: @Matt yes, slowly getting to those suggestions, thank you!

Comment: Looks like expanding the sleep time to 2000 ms is getting things done. I really wish I could just use 7Zip.

Comment: So you are restricted to using PSv2? 7Zip is portable... can you not bundle that with your script then?

Comment: Yeah, PSv2, and 7Zip is to be nowhere in our environment. :(

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing the same issue that [others have noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55628092/how-to-reliably-copy-items-with-powershell-to-an-mtp-device/55638981#55638981) when using the 
`Shell.Application`'s `CopyHere()` command. It's asynchronous (non-blocking) and doesn't report completed events.

Adding a `Sleep()` won't work reliably for large files because the `Shell.Application` object will be disposed and disconnect from its child threads before they've completed.

Try repeatedly checking for the existence of the destination file like in the linked answer. Hope this helps!